# Panda3D - Setting date

Tags: python, panda3d

I am trying to make that every screenshot file end with a date.
It does work, but the problem is that when i take a new screenshot, its always the same date.

Heres the code

```
class ScrShot(object):    
    def Screenie(self):
            file_name = Filename('WFT-ScreenShot-'+str(date)+'.jpg')
            base.win.saveScreenshot(file_name) 
            print ':debug: screenshot taken!'
            print ':debug: screenshot saved as ', file_name ,''

instance = ScrShot()

base.accept('f9', instance.Screenie)
```

and heres the variable used:

```
###########################################
#time
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
###########################################
```

Plus, something from the log:

```
:debug: screenshot taken!
:debug: screenshot saved as  WFT-ScreenShot-2013-12-24-18-46-04.jpg
:debug: screenshot taken!
:debug: screenshot saved as  WFT-ScreenShot-2013-12-24-18-46-04.jpg
:debug: screenshot taken!
:debug: screenshot saved as  WFT-ScreenShot-2013-12-24-18-46-04.jpg
```

Now, any another method to update the date?

EDIT: It did fix the problem, but i also wanted to save in a external folder.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can save to an external folder by prepending the appropriate path to the Filename passed.  For instance, Filename('/c/path/to/WFT-Screenshot' + ...)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your class with:

```
class ScrShot(object):    
    def Screenie(self):
        file_name = Filename('WFT-ScreenShot-'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'))+'.jpg')
        base.win.saveScreenshot(file_name) 
        print ':debug: screenshot taken!'
        print ':debug: screenshot saved as ', file_name ,''
```

It outputs all the same date because you assigned `date` only once. It dosesn't update automatically when you use `date`. You have to call `now()` **everytime** when you want to get a new date.